# firefox addon sdk: get page load time

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

When using this Firefox Addon SDK example:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open({
  url: "http://www.example.com",
  onReady: runScript
});

function runScript(tab) {
  tab.attach({
    contentScript: "document.body.style.border = '5px solid red';"
  });
  console.log(tab.title);
}
```

How can I get the **page load time** and print it to the console?

(like the app.telemetry Addon does - http://www.apptelemetry.com/de/page-speed-monitor.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Navigation Timing API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var t = performance.timing;
    console.log(t.loadEventEnd - t.responseEnd);
  }, 0);
}
```

Notice that it's a Javascript API so it must run inside a [Content Script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts) (ie, it won't work inside your lib/main.js or index.js file).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The second parameter to setTimeout ("0") means the Timer-Function is called immediately? Why do I need the timer then at all? Thanks